# How to Fix 'column "0" of relation "credential" does not exist'?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

This is what inside Controller:

```
DB::table('credential')->where('id', 1)->update([
    'clientid' => $credential[0]->clientid,
    'clientsecret' => $credential[0]->clientsecret,
    'redirect_uri' => $credential[0]->redirect_uri,
    'token', $curl->response->access_token
]);
```

But i got error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "0" of relation "credential" does not exist LINE 1: ..." = $1, "clientsecret" = $2, "redirect_uri" = $3, "0" = $4, ... | (SQL: update "credential" set "clientid" = myvalue, "clientsecret" = myvalue, "redirect_uri" = http://myvalue, "0" = token, "1" = mypointvalue where "id" = 1)
```

Any ideas how i can fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your query, `'token'`, `$curl->response->access_token` are taken as two array elements instead of a single associative array member. correct it like this,

```
DB::table('credential')->where('id', 1)->update([
    'clientid' => $credential[0]->clientid,
    'clientsecret' => $credential[0]->clientsecret,
    'redirect_uri' => $credential[0]->redirect_uri,
    'token'=> $curl->response->access_token
]);
```